# How to Render options of an form with the values fetched from the database with php?

Tags: php, html

I have been building a html form where the options of the drop down list created with the  tag where the options are rendered to the drop down with the values fetched from the database. I have echoed the option tag but it only shows as <?php in the dropdown.
I have included two variables and tried to render it to the dropdown, but it also not working. what am I doing wrong here?

```
 <select name="breakfastCaters" id="cater" class="breakfastCaters">
                            <?php 
                                $val1="A";
                                $val2="B";
                                echo `<option value="nonVeg" class="option">.$val1.</option>`; 
                                echo `<option value="nonVeg" class="option">.$val2.</option>`; 
                            ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Did you install PHP?

Comment: yes, other php codes are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using the inline php for html

Render the HTML, then change the values using php.

```html
 <select name="breakfastCaters" id="cater" class="breakfastCaters">
   <?php $val1="A"; $val2="B"; ?>

  <option value="nonVeg" class="option"> <?= echo $val1 ?> </option>
  <option value="nonVeg" class="option"><?= echo $val2 ?></option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Update your answer or try to explain more depthfully, I'm not really understanding what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. but my real requirement is like this. I want to display values fetched from the database. when i call getServices() inside the select tag, it should render the options.

```
function getServices(){
        global $dbConnection;
        $sql="SELECT * FROM cateringservice WHERE breakfast='y'";
        $res= $dbConnection->query($sql);
        if($res->num_rows>0){
            while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
                echo(`<option value=`.$row['caterId'].[`class="option">`.$row['caterId'].[`</option>;`]]); 
                
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to start and close the html with single quote (') before appending PHP variable in your code like below.

```
 <select name="breakfastCaters" id="cater" class="breakfastCaters">
                            <?php 
                                $val1="A";
                                $val2="B";
                                echo '<option value="nonVeg" class="option">'.$val1.'</option>'; 
                                echo '<option value="nonVeg" class="option">'.$val2.'</option>'; 
                            ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Check below modified code snippet -

```
function getServices(){
    global $dbConnection;
    $sql="SELECT * FROM cateringservice WHERE breakfast='y'";
    $res= $dbConnection->query($sql);
    if($res->num_rows>0){
        echo '<select>';
        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['caterId'].'" class="option">'.$row['caterId'].'</option>';
            
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```